# How to escape a JSON variable posted with curl in bash script?

Tags: bash, curl, mandrill

I'm submitting a message to Mandrill in a bash script via their API and the content of the 'message' variable is causing the API call to come back with an error:

```
An error occured: {"status":"error","code":-1,"name":"ValidationError","message":"You must specify a key value"}
```

The content of the $message_body variable is:

```
Trigger: Network traffic high on 'server'
Trigger status: PROBLEM
Trigger severity: Average
Trigger URL:

Item values:

1. Network traffic inbound (server:net.if.in[eth0,bytes]): 3.54 MBytes
2. Network traffic outbound (server:net.if.out[eth0,bytes]): 77.26 KBytes
3. *UNKNOWN* (*UNKNOWN*:*UNKNOWN*): *UNKNOWN*

Original event ID: 84
```

I'm not sure what part of the string is throwing it off, but it seems that something is causing the JSON to be invalid when submitted to Mandrill's API.

If I change the above message to something simple such as "Testing 123" the message gets submitted successfully.

The code that does the POST is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
message_body = `cat message.txt`
msg='{ "async": false, "key": "'$key'", "message": { "from_email": "'$from_email'", "from_name": "'$from_name'", "headers": { "Reply-To": "'$reply_to'" }, "auto_html": false, "return_path_domain": null, "subject": "'$2'", "text": "'$message_body'", "to": [ { "email": "'$1'", "type": "to" } ] } }'
results=$(curl -A 'Mandrill-Curl/1.0' -d "$msg" 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json' -s 2>&1);
echo "$results"
```

What can I do to make sure the `$message_body` variable is prepared and ready to be submitted as valid JSON?

Comment: change to `message_body=$(cat message.txt)` or if you want to really amaze your colleagues, `m_b=$(< message.txt)`. ;-). All variable assignments in bash/ksh must NOT have spaces around the `=` sign. There may be other problems in your code, but you'd have to add an example of `$message_body` to your question that breaks your script. (don't reply in comments, please). Also, indicate if you can send a very simple `msg_bdy`? quote chars, `[$&#%*(){}]` chars all have meaning to the shell so they have to be escaped or otherwise dealt with. Maybe `$"${message_body}"` (an ANSI string) will help.

Comment: If you want to be **absolutely** positive that `message_body` is valid JSON, use a JSON-specific tool such as `jq` to generate it; that'll cover all the corner cases -- literal quotes &c. Unless `jq` is told to use a non-JSON output format, it literally cannot emit content which is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the lack of quoting around your variables

```
msg='{ "async": false, "key": "'$key'", "message": { "from_email": "'$from_email'", "from_name": "'$from_name'", "headers": { "Reply-To": "'$reply_to'" }, "auto_html": false, "return_path_domain": null, "subject": "'$2'", "text": "'$message_body'", "to": [ { "email": "'$1'", "type": "to" } ] } }'
# ..............................^^^^ no quotes around var ...........^^^^^^^^^^^...................^^^^^^^^^^...............................^^^^^^^^^...................................................................^^..............^^^^^^^^^^^^^.........................^^
```

Try this instead: any double quote in each variable is escaped.

```
escape_quotes() { echo "${1//\"/\\\"}"; }
msg=$(
    printf '{ "async": false, "key": "%s", "message": { "from_email": "%s", "from_name": "%s", "headers": { "Reply-To": "%s" }, "auto_html": false, "return_path_domain": null, "subject": "%s", "text": "%s", "to": [ { "email": "%s", "type": "to" } ] } }' \
        "$(escape_quotes "$key")"          \
        "$(escape_quotes "$from_email")"   \
        "$(escape_quotes "$from_name")"    \
        "$(escape_quotes "$reply_to")"     \
        "$(escape_quotes "$2")"            \
        "$(escape_quotes "$message_body")" \
        "$(escape_quotes "$1")" 
)
```